# Where can I get the latest DirectShow developer runtime?

Tags: sdk, directshow

I've found DirectShow developer runtime only in dxsdk_feb2005_extras.exe. It is rather old and supports only WinXP. Where can I get the more recent version of debug directshow files?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. DirectShow SDK were included in the DirectX SDK and the last version of the DirectX SDK to include DirectShow was DirectX 9.0 SDK Update - (February 2005) Extras.

but after that DirectShow was moved to the Windows SDK and you can get it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa904949.aspx)

Comment: There are DirectShow headers and libs but I cannot find debug runtime :(